# Create Image Button using Code-behind

Tags: c#, image, button, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create a three-state Image Button in run time. There is existing method in XAML but I wonder how to do it in code behind (i.e. how to translate the following code to C#)?

```
<Button>
   <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Grid>
            <Image Name="Normal" Source="Resources/Normal.png"/>
            <Image Name="Pressed" Source="Resources/Pressed.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <Image Name="Disabled" Source="Resources/Disabled.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
         </Grid>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
               <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
               <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a panel control in your page, then in your code behind use this:

```
ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
imgBtn.ID = "image_id";
imgBtn.ImageUrl = "your_image_path";
Panel1.Controls.Add (imgBtn);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You are using an Image as a button, but what I'm trying to achieve is to set an image inside a button without the need to override the original mouse properties. anyway, one vote for you.

Comment: Because your Question is ImageButton, so... If you want to change the image of he button (background?) you can do something like this: `Button1.Attributes.Add("class", "className");`, in the className (css) you define the image for the button.